# What's the difference between caller- and callee-saved registers?

Tags: c++

In particular, how can you know the number of save/restore operations executed for variables in a piece of code in a caller-saved register vs callee-saved register?

Comment: Which operating system? Which architecture? Which C++ compiler? Which C++ compiler version?

Comment: [What are callee and caller saved registers?](//stackoverflow.com/q/9268586) is a duplicate for the title question.

Answer (score 6):

Caller-saved registers, also known as volatile registers, are any CPU core registers that a calling function must save (generally to the runtime stack) if the calling function needs the value in the register; i.e. if the value is "live".  Callee-saved registers, also known as nonvolatile registers, are any CPU core registers that contain values that a function must promise to not destroy.  If the callee (called function) needs to use those registers, it must first save the values in those registers (generally on the runtime stack), and then restore them before returning back to the caller.

As Carl Norum mentions, which CPU core regs are caller-save & which are callee-save are defined by a calling convention (historically poorly documented, and historically compiler-specific), or defined by a ABI (Application Binary Interface).

Although its information is decidedly x86-specific, the following document by Agner Fog does a really good job of describing calling conventions & caller-save/callee-save registers:

http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf

The following describes the PowerPC EABI, including its calling convention.  But in this document, search for "volatile" and "nonvolatile" (caller-save and callee-save, respectively):

http://www.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/app_note/PPCEABI.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Physically, there is no difference between a caller-saved and a callee-saved register.  The distinction is made only by a procedure call standard (calling convention) or ABI.  If you need to analyze a piece of code, you can compile it (but not assemble) or disassemble a binary and go through it function by function and instruction by instruction, using an ABI or calling convention manual as a reference.