# What is the state of the registers after a function call?

Tags: c++, c, assembly

I have limited knowledge in assembly, but I can at least read through it and match with the corresponding C or C++ code. I can see that the function arguments are passed either by pushing them to the stack or by registers, and the function body uses some registers to do its operations. But it also seems to use the same registers that were used in the caller. Does this mean that the caller has no guarantee that the state of the registers will be the same after a function call? What if the whole body of the function is unknown during compilation? How does the compiler deal with this?

Comment: It depends on the [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) of the function. For x86 cdecl, EAX is the return value, and ECX and EDX must be saved by the caller; the rest must be saved by the callee.

Comment: Not only the calling convention but the specific compiler's strategy with respect to optimisation as well as its own idiosyncrasies.

Comment: The answer depends mostly upon the compiler and operating system.

Comment: For ARM, it is the ARM Procedure Call Standard (AAPCS) and the language-specific Application Binary Interface (ABI). You can download them freely from their website.

Comment: The question is currently far too broad. You'll have to specify in more detail. Also, these are multiple questions actually.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590215/whats-the-difference-between-caller-and-callee-saved-registers) for some details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler-generated assembler code follows some [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention). A calling convention typically specifies

- how are arguments passed to the function
- how return values are passed from the called function to the caller
- which registers should be saved within a function call and which can be modified

If all functions being called follow the same calling convention, no problems with using the same registers should occur.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments allude to, the fact is that there is no standard for this. It is left entirely to the implementors of the particular c++ compiler you are using.

A more explicit question, like this: "when compiling on version N of compiler A with compiler options B, calling a function signature of C, for target CPU D, using ABI E, what are the guarantees vis-a-vis register preservation?"

In which case an expert (or the manual) on that particular toolset can answer.

As you can probably infer, for any kind of industrial-strength project, it's the wrong question to ask, because as your compiler evolves the answer will change, and you don't want that fact to impact the reliability of your program.

It's a good question, because it's nice to know what the compiler is doing under the hood - it aids learning.

But on the whole, the golden rule is to express clear uncomplicated logic to the compiler in your program, and allow the compiler to handle the details of turning that logic into optimised machine code, at which modern compilers are excellent.

Comment: It is not just the compiler, but mostly the language, the architecture/CPU and the OS. For some architectures, there are multiple ABIs (e.g. ARM, x86 - depneding on Windows or Linux (OS-X?)).

Comment: @Olaf indeed so, I meant for the term 'compiler' to catch all that, but I'll make it explicit in the answer.

Comment: Well you're making it too generic...If I declare a function foo() with C calling convention on x86 architecture on Windows then...I'll always know what will happen, no matters compiler version (or its options). If it was not like that you won't even be able to call OS library functions.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti yes... except that the last time I used a microsoft compiler on windows there were 3 calling conventions that could be used in the same program... stdcall, fastcall and something else (pascal?). Forgive me, it's been a while since I sullied myself with visual horror show :)