# C to assembly issue , I do not know why my function is not working and I always get 0xFFFFFFFE 0x0000000C

Tags: c, assembly, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

I need to "translate " the function ChangeVector to assembly without using variables (I have to use for example push ebp..mov ebp, esp ... but my problem is that the original code works perfectly, but when I try to translate ChangeVector, I get all the time for all the cases before and after assigning : 0xFFFFFFFE 0X0000000C, and that is not correct , for example for this case: n = 2, elements = -2,12 .. i = 1, k=5, v=1 Exit : 0XFFFFFFFF 0X0842108c.

As I said in the original code I get the right answer but I was asked just to tanslate ChangeVector without variables and I dont know how because what I have tried never worked. Please helppp!! thanks

This is the original code:

```
void changeBit(unsigned int *vector, int indice, int valor) {
    int posicion = indice / 32; // Find the position in the vector where the bit will be
    int bit = 31 - (indice % 32); // Identify the bit within the vector position

    __asm {
        mov esi, vector
        mov edi, posicion
        mov ecx, bit
        mov eax, dword ptr [esi + edi * 4] ; Load the current value from the vector

        cmp valor, 0
        jne set_bit ; Jump to set_bit if the value is not zero

        btr [esi + edi * 4], ecx ; Reset the bit at the specified position
        jmp done

    set_bit:
        mov edx, 1
        shl edx, cl ; Move 1 to the correct position
        or dword ptr [esi + edi * 4], edx ; Set the bit to 1 using OR
    done:
    }
}

void changeVector(unsigned int *vector, int n, int i, int k, int v) { 
    // Loop to cover all bits to change starting from position i and jumping by k.
    for (int j = 0; (i + j * k) < n * 32; j++) { 
        changeBit(vector, (i + j * k), v); // Call the function that changes the bit with its respective position and the value to change to
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    do {
        printf("Enter the size of the vector (n): ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if (n <= 0) 
        {
            printf("The size of the vector must be greater than 0. Please try again.\n");
        }
    } while (n <= 0); 

    unsigned int *vector = (unsigned int *)calloc(n, sizeof(unsigned int)); 

    if (vector == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory for the vector.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter values for each element of the vector:\n"); 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Enter the value of the element: ");
        scanf("%u", &vector[i]);
    }

    int i, k, v; 
    printf("Enter the initial index (i): ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("Enter the step (k): ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    printf("Enter the value (v, 0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d", &v);

    printf("The original unsigned int vector (size %d) would be:\n", n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("0x%08X \n", vector[i]);
    }
    changeVector(vector, n, i, k, v);
    printf("\nAfter the assignment, the vector is:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("0x%08X \n", vector[i]);
    }

    free(vector);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my attempt for ChangeVector that is not working at all,

```
void changeVector(unsigned int *vector, int n, int i, int k, int v) {
    __asm {
        mov esi, vector    ; Vector address
        mov ecx, n         ; Number of elements in the vector
        mov edx, i         ; Initial index
        mov ebx, k         ; Step

    loop_start:
        cmp edx, ecx      ; Compare the index with the vector size
        jge loop_end       ; If index >= size, exit the loop

        ; Calculate the bit index based on the current index (edx)
        mov eax, edx       ; Copy the index to eax
        imul eax, 32       ; Multiply index by 32
        mov edi, eax       ; Save the result in edi

        ; Call the changeBit function with the calculated bit index (edi) and value (v)
        push v
        push edi
        push esi
        call changeBit
        add esp, 12        ; Clean up the stack after the function call

        ; Update the index (edx) based on the step (ebx)
        add edx, ebx

        jmp loop_start     ; Jump back to the beginning of the loop

    loop_end:
    }
}
```

Comment: This is still not [webassembly] for the JavaScript VM, it's x86 assembly in C++.  Also, in future, edit your existing question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77549915/c-to-assembly-issue-my-code-is-printing-the-same-thing-before-and-after-0xfffff) instead of posting a new one and deleting.  My comments there about using `bts` and `btr` are even more applicable to this case, where you're trying to avoid the `int posicion = indice / 32;` part.  Or you can do it manually, see [Sieve of Eratosthenes in x86 assembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/548870)

Comment: @MichaelPetch yes! specifically I am using Notepad++ and VS2015x86 Native tool command prompt / Windows

Comment: @PeterCordes I deleted it because I forgot to translate my Spanish comments and function names to English, I translated it and post it again , sorry and thank you, also I took and ss of your answer!!

Comment: Well like I said, next time just click the [edit] button.  A post needing improvement should be edited, not reposted.  But at this point you might as well keep this one open, I guess, instead of undeleting and editing the old one.

Comment: The limit for the loop is `n * 32` and not `n` and the `indice` calculation is `i + j * k` and not `i` so when you do the comparison `cmp  edx,ecx` the two registers do not have the correct value for `(i + j * k) < n * 32`. Since `n` doesn't change, calculate `n * 32` before the label `loop_start`.  After the label `loop_start` and before the comparison, calculate `I + j * k` and then do the comparison and if the result is less than `n * 32` push the calculated value along with the other arguments onto the stack and call `changeBit`.

Comment: Ecx and Edx is changed after call changeBit and already not valid on next loop. You can use [FAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fa-fa-listing-file?view=msvc-170) for take asm from your src. Also be more useful use masm instead inline asm

Comment: See also this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139933/what-is-the-state-of-the-registers-after-a-function-call as well as SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603003/what-registers-must-be-preserved-by-an-x86-function